# How to grab 2nd element of querySelectorAll and loop thru its elements using Puppeteer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Im trying to scrape this website, their website layout uses the same class name for the information that I need. I tried using document.querySelectorAll() but it returns undefined.

`let shoeHtml = await page.evaluate( () => document.querySelectorAll('.form-section-right'))`

If i try `let shoeHtml = await page.evaluate( () => document.querySelectorAll('.form-section-right')[1].innerHTML)` it returns a string and I'm unable to loop thru it and grab the information I need

Heres the html code. https://pastebin.com/dHbbu5EG

The information I want to grab is the `a` tags. I would also like to click them.

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate` only returns serializable data and in-page objects are not serializable. You need to either use [`evaluateHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) or `page.$$` which is the equivalent of `querySelectorAll` in the puppeteer execution context.

```js
let shoeHtml = await page.$$('.form-section-right');
```

Accessing element's properties in puppeteer context:

```js
const innerHTML = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, shoeHtml[1]);
```

or

```js
const innerHTML = await (await shoeHtml[1].getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue();
```

Comment: console.log(shoeHtml[1].innerHTML)

Comment: @NinoSoles That element is in puppeteer context, you can't access element's properties like that. edited the answer.